# Laravel changing the attribute name on eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a `group` attribute in my model and I want to change the group attribute to `sub-group` if the group parent is not 0.

My code:

```
public function setGroupAttribute
{
    $group_id = $this->attribute['id'];

    $group = Group::find($group_id);

    if ($group->parent != 0)
    {
        $this->attribute['group'] = 'sub-group';
    }
}
```

But I guess what I'm doing is wrong? So how do I do this right? I just want to change the attribute and not the data inside.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `$this->attribute['group']` to a string of 'sub-group' rather than re-indexing it.  Try this instead...

```
$this->attribute['sub-group'] = $this->attribute['group'];
unset($this->attribute['group']);
```

Comment: Still does not work. On another note `network` is from a function BelongsTo().